# How do I call a suspend function from a React button onClick event in Kotlin/JS?

Tags: reactjs, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-js

I want to fetch some data when a button is pressed. I know how to do it using promises and continuations (see the sample below) but I'd like to learn how to do it using suspend functions.

As an example:

```kotlin
import kotlinx.browser.window
import react.FC
import react.Props
import react.dom.html.ReactHTML.button
import react.dom.html.ReactHTML.div
import react.useState
import kotlin.coroutines.resume
import kotlin.coroutines.resumeWithException
import kotlin.coroutines.suspendCoroutine

val MyComponent = FC<Props> {
    var text by useState("Click Load")
    div { +text }
    button {
        +"Load"
        onClick = {
            text = "Loading..."
            window.fetch("https://catfact.ninja/fact").then { response ->
                response.text().then { receivedText ->
                    text = receivedText
                }
            }
            
            //text = fetchCat() //This line does not compile
        }
    }
}

suspend fun fetchCat() = suspendCoroutine<String> { continuation ->
    window.fetch("https://catfact.ninja/fact")
        .then { response ->
            response.text()
                .then { text -> continuation.resume(text) }
                .catch { continuation.resumeWithException(it) }
        }
        .catch { continuation.resumeWithException(it) }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reference to `kotlinx.coroutines` needs to be added to gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4")
}
```

Then a MainScope is created globally (a single instance is used for the whole application), using which suspend functions can be called.

```kotlin
import kotlinx.browser.window
import kotlinx.coroutines.MainScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import react.FC
import react.Props
import react.dom.html.ReactHTML.button
import react.dom.html.ReactHTML.div
import react.useState
import kotlin.coroutines.resume
import kotlin.coroutines.resumeWithException
import kotlin.coroutines.suspendCoroutine

val mainScope = MainScope()

val MyComponent = FC<Props> {
    var text by useState("Click Load")
    div { +text }
    button {
        +"Load"
        onClick = {
            text = "Loading..."

            mainScope.launch {
                text = fetchCat()
            }
        }
    }
}

suspend fun fetchCat() = suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
    window.fetch("https://catfact.ninja/fact")
        .then { response ->
            response.text()
                .then { text -> continuation.resume(text) }
                .catch { continuation.resumeWithException(it) }
        }
        .catch { continuation.resumeWithException(it) }
}
```